# Getting an image to appear over another div onclick with a toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I am trying to be able to click on a specific square and get a checkmark to appear over-top of it. I am going to want it to have a toggle effect, but I wanted to try to at least get the checkmark to show, which I am really having an issue getting it to even appear.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.package-img').click(function () {
        //target.innerHTML = '<img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">';
        $('.package-img').prepend('<img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">')
    });
```

```css
.package-img {
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
    position: relative;
}
#calendar-wrap, #tp-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.checkmark-img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar-wrap">
  <h2 class="product-titles">Package 1</h2>
  <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 1" class="package-img" id="calendar-img">
</div>
<div id="calendar-wrap">
  <h2 class="product-titles">Package 2</h2>
  <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 2" class="package-img" id="tp-img">
</div>
```

Comment: use a checkbox to retain the value. I have updated my answer to contain a css only version. No Javascript required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is understood what you are looking for. Basically you can "toggle" the checkmark image over the checkmark square image when you click on the checkmark square. The problem with this is once you put the checkmark over the square the toggle doesnt work anymore. I have come up with a solution that should work a little better.

Basically if we take advantage of the rules that when a `label` is selected that is bound to a `<input type="checkbox" />` this will `toggle` the `checked` property of the checkbox.

We can then bind to this event in jQuery and show\hide the checkmark. In this instance we dont bind any click events to the images, but the `change` event of the checkbox. Something like the example below.

Now the question is:

> Why did i use a checkbox

Well by using a checkbox we can capture the result in our form posts. It also makes it easy to identify what is checked by enumerating all the check boxes that have the `checked` property.

To have this sent to your server you will need to add a `name` property to each checkbox and also set the `value` property.

```js
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    $(this).parents('.calendar-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').show();
  else
    $(this).parents('.calendar-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').hide();

});
```

```css
.package-img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  position: relative;
}

#calendar-wrap,
#tp-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.calendar-check {
  display: none;
}

.package-check-toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar-wrap" class="calendar-wrap">
  <h2 class="product-titles">Package 1</h2>
  <label for="package-check-1" class="package-check-toggle">
    <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 1" class="package-img" id="calendar-img" />
    <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" alt="Package 1" class="checkmark-img" />
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="package-check-1" />
</div>
<div id="calendar-wrap" class="calendar-wrap">
  <h2 class="product-titles">Package 2</h2>
  <label for="package-check-2" class="package-check-toggle">
    <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 2" class="package-img" id="calendar-img" />
    <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" alt="Package 2" class="checkmark-img" />
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="package-check-2" />
</div>
```

Sample [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zdnrq41/1/)

**EDIT**
For completness sakes I figured best to show a CSS (3) only solution. This has no depenedcies on using jQuery at all. Again this takes into consideration a checkbox (which is value based) and toggles the checkmark based on the toggle.

The Markup is quite simple.

```
<div class="calendar-checkmark">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox1" value="true" />
    <label for="checkbox-1"></label>
</div>
```

Example:

```css
.calendar-checkmark input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

.calendar-checkmark label {
    cursor:pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 384px;
    width: 354px;
    position:relative;
    background: url('http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif') no-repeat center center transparent;
}

.calendar-checkmark label::after {
    content:' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    display:none;
    background: url('https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png') no-repeat center center transparent;
}

.calendar-checkmark input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    display: block;
        
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar-checkmark">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox1" value="true" />
    <label for="checkbox-1"></label>
</div>
```

The trick here is using [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) which allow you to select an adjacent sibling based of another element. So if we look at the css when the checkbox is checked it gets the [Psudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) `:checked` applied to it (similar to `:hover` etc). Then we use the adjacent `+` selector to locate the `label`.

Now the label element has a css background set to the image of the square box. Next it has the psudo-class `::after` applied which creates our psudo-element that contains the checkbox. This is added after the element, when the checkbox is `checked` the psudo class `:checked` is addeed. This then changes the state of the psudo element by displaying the element.

[Another Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ajwt3x6/)

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of this so well. I changed my answer to yours as I like being able to capture the values. Quick question : When I click on the element, how can I get the value and print it on the page? IE: I click on box 1 and then box 2. Elsewhere on the page it would say box1 & box2.

Comment: You can bind to the `change` event for the checkboxes to update your page. To get a list of the checked boxes you can do something like `$('.calendar-check:checked')` which returns a jQuery array that contains all the values that are checked.

Answer (score 3):

Use `before` method instead of `prepend`, otherwise your image is being added inside another image. Also use `$(this).before...` otherwise your checkmark will be added to all images with class `package-img`

```
$(this).before('<img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">')
```

```js
var $img = $('<img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img"/>').hide();
$('.package-img').before($img);

$('.package-img').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().show();
});

$('.checkmark-img').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.package-img {
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
    position: relative;
}
#calendar-wrap, #tp-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.checkmark-img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar-wrap">
  <h2 class="product-titles">Package 1</h2>
  <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 1" class="package-img" id="calendar-img">
</div>
<div id="calendar-wrap">
  <h2 class="product-titles">Package 2</h2>
  <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 2" class="package-img" id="tp-img">
</div>
```

Comment: This adds a bunch of checks at the top of the page?

Comment: @Paul I think that's related to your CSS - if you want it in the box you'll have to use positioning more accurately

Comment: Is there anyway to make this a toggle?

Comment: I added `position:absolute` and a left offset, also changed the height to make it center over the box. You can tweak it as you like.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Thanks! Is there anyway to incorporate toggle into it? I tried doing this, but it just toggles the parent... `$(this).toggle().before('<img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">');`

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Thanks! Is there anyway to assign a value to the one I clicked?

Comment: Sure.  What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a lot simpler if we just remove the box images and create them via CSS. There will be less to download and we can then make the box's background transparent. This will allow us to just show and hide the checkmark that is already sitting behind each box.

```js
$('.package-img').click(function () {
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
parent { position:relative; }

.package-img {
   border:3px solid black;
   width: 110px;
   height:110px;
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
   margin-left: 20%;
   cursor: pointer;
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
}

.checkmark-img {
    transition:1s;
    width: 15%;
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-15%;
    
}

img.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="product-titles">Package 1</h2>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="package-img"></div>
  <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img hide">
</div>

<h2 class="product-titles">Package 2</h2>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="package-img"></div>
  <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img hide">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. absolutely position the Checkmark on top of the package image**

**2. Hide it**

**3. Use toggle to reveal it**

> since its hidden on top of it you will need to use the siblings selector to retrieve it

```js
 $('.checkmark-img').hide();
 $('.package-img').click(function () {
    $('.checkmark-img').toggle();
 });
```

```css
.package-img {
        width: 60%;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 20%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
        position: relative;
    }
    #calendar-wrap, #tp-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .checkmark-img {
        width: 60%;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-top:10%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
       
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar-wrap">
      <h2 class="product-titles">Package 1</h2>
      <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">'
      <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 1" class="package-img" id="calendar-img">
</div>
<div id="calendar-wrap">
      <h2 class="product-titles">Package 2</h2>
       <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">'
      <img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif" alt="Package 2" class="package-img" id="tp-img">
      
</div>
```